# Facebook SDK - Using JS to Auth and PHP for the rest?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

I am trying to use the Facebook PHP and JS SDKs together in order to create a web app that will double as a canvas app. In the current setup I am experiencing issues when the page is left or a while and the system reverts back to the login screen. It is important to not I am using a dynamic domain mapper and there are a few possible URLs /dev/, /dev/pool/, /dev/pool/edit/, etc. that the user might visit and experience the app.

I read around and found that authorizing with the JS SDK is the correct method (I could be wrong?) and then using the PHP SDK to sort through everything else will work just find, gaining the access token naturally.

I know this is something wrong with my authentication setup, as I see it reload sometimes, I also get stuck with a login button that doesn't do anything if I am on a sub page, and if I don't touch the site for a couple of minutes the system tries to re-auth for no reason.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

**Here is the JS set up on my site:**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: 'XXXXX',
      channelUrl: 'http://www.domain.com/channel.php',
      status: true,
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true,
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      alert('refreshing')
      window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810 });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();

  };

  (function(d, debug){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document, /*debug*/ true));
</script>
```

**Here is the PHP flow of calling the Facebook Object**

```
$fb = new FbDoa();
if ($fb->isAuthed() === false) {
  echo $fb->getLoginButton();
}
else {
  echo $fb->getProfileInfo();
}
```

---

**Here is the PHP contents of the FbDoa Object (`$fb`):**

```
public function __construct() {
  require_once(Facebook/facebook.php');
  $this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'XXXXX',
    'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXX', 
    'cookie' => true,
  ));

  $this->user = $this->facebook->getUser();
  if ($this->user) {
    try {
      // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
      $this->user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      //echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
      $this->user = null;
    }
  }
}

public function isAuthed() {
  if ($this->user) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

public function getLoginButton() {
  $scope = 'email,user_likes,friends_likes,publish_actions,publish_stream,read_friendlists';
  return '<fb:login-button size="xlarge" perms="'.$scope.'"></fb:login-button>';
} 

public function getProfileInfo() {
  return $this->user_profile;
}
```

---

---

UPDATE 1: 
It really seems like `window.location.reload();` is not doing anything, if I hit the login button over and over nothing happens, but I refresh it works. That being true the app's auth should last longer than a couple mins, which means there are a few issues before me. Any ideas?

UPDATE 2:
The issue could be with my server-side code? anyone know anything about PHP+JS SDK?

Answer (score 0):

The signed request is saved in a cookie similar to `fbsr_appid`. From that you can use the `code` to deal with it. Here is how your flow should look

[image: Auth Hybrid Flow]

As long as there is a base url in your app settings it should redirect to all.

Comment: If I auth with JS the access_token never appears within PHP for me though, though I am able to see the return of API call to '/me'

Comment: @Gates if `/me` returns then you have authentication

Comment: So then I do not need to get the access token? I just wrote up an update above explain how clicking the login button results in no changes but a refresh after does work as well as the request for auth and login should last longer than a couple mins. Does this mean I am checking auth incorrectly? OR Does this mean I am auth'ing incorrectly?

Comment: @Gates since you are using canvas try `window.location = window.location` instead

Comment: Its not alway canvas though, sometimes its outside, the error I see is actually outside.

Comment: @Gates okay you should still try since `reload()` will re `POST` while you really just need the PHP SDK to get the cookie. After I would suggest following where auth is lost

Comment: Trying it, Mind if I FB message you since we should "avoid extended discussions"

Comment: @Gates you can find me at irc.freenode #facebook